# Tethering blocked with message about contacting provider

Tags: ios, tethering

Sometimes when I want to use tethering I get a message that I need to ask my provider.  How can I "unblock" the Personal Hotspot feature so it always works?
(In the phone, obviously)

Phone is not under contract and tethering on Android works with the same provider. There is no reason it should not work with my end provider.

Comment: About "off-topic".  This is a specific problem for an Apple product.

Comment: The SIM card is not an Apple product, and the first step to take here is to contact the Customer Support team of your mobile carrier. Problem could easily be a configuration issue on their side or a slightly defective SIM card. If they can't or won't help you, feel free to come back, update question accordingly and have it reopened.

Comment: As I said, I only have the problem with the iPhone.  Besides, the question is about how I can fix it IN THE PHONE.  For example when I travel, i often buy a local card, and its very inconvenient if I can't use it as a hotspot.

Comment: You didn't mention whether you have the problem only with one SIM card or also with other card (from different carriers). Still, the problem remains the same: the iPhone displays whatever the SIM tells it to.

Comment: I've solved the problem for my case.  Added the answer to the question, as question is put on hold.

Comment: I've reopened the question in case you want to move the answer to the answer section and accept it. Thanks for coming back with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phone had separate APN settings for "MOBILE DATA" and "PERSONAL HOTSPOT".  Copying from the mobile data ones solved the problems.

(With this provider, the date settings are often not be set automatically when switching SIM, at least on Android.  Also I don't remember the two settings to be separate.)

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to do as the message says and contact your provider.

Comment: Obviously that is not what I want.

Comment: @Olav "Obviously"? Why not? The message (which you haven't actually provided in its entirety) is quite clear.

Comment: It is obviously IOS that decides to block these features.

Comment: @Olav That's not true at all, iOS is specifically telling you it's the carrier; it wouldn't do that if it was an iOS setting. iOS uses the carrier settings that it downloads using the SIM.

Comment: Still, what I want to know is how I fix it in the phone.

Comment: @Olav See my previous comment